# Will the COVID-19 virus ever stop mutating into new variants?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, virus, coronavirus

I am curious to know if it has been discussed within the medical community as to whether the COVID-19 virus will ever stop mutating into new variants, and if it has been discussed, what is the consensus on this particular issue?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I think this would be better suited to the biology SE, but it would definitely be closed there because it shows a complete lack of any attempt to answer it for yourself. It will likely be closed here for the same reason.

Comment: @bob1, I understand what you're saying and I agree with you that this needed to be closed. I was just thinking that before I start doing my own research concerning this question about COVID-19, that it would be worth first asking the MS.SE community about it to see if there is already a definitive answer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't stop mutating. Mutating is a feature of life with nucleic acids, no matter if you are a virus, bacterium, archaea, fungi, plant or animal.

You can check on mutation rates in organisms with a simple google search for the terms "mutation rate (species of interest)"